# Generate random number in vdm++

Tags: random, vdm++

Does anyone know how to generate a random number in vdm++? The math library doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the random generator in VDM (Both in VDMTools and Overture).

In Overture the argument must be larger than 0 and the seed must be set, which it is by default. Remember to include the standard MATH lib by selecting the project in the explorer and New->Add VDM Library and selecting MATH.

It can be called like this: `MATH.rand(100)` which will return a number between 0 and 100.

The seed can be changed through `MATH.srand(5)` it returns the seed set.